# Untiy LeanTween easing giving me strange results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tween, leantween

I'm using LeanTween engine and all was going well until I tried this:

```
LeanTween.moveY (menuPanel, 1200f, 0.5f)
            .setEase (LeanTweenType.easeInOutBack);
```

The goal is to have the menu panel move down slightly before shooting up out of the screen. The easeInOutBack seemed the correct type (based on [Easing Cheatsheet](http://easings.net/)).

menuPanel is a GameObject UI Panel of which I declare as public and assign in the inspector.

Instead it goes a little crazy, bouncing up and down sporadically whilst moving a bit.

Has anyone observed this behaviour before, know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: just FWIW are you using `Layout` and the other automatic spacing features?

Comment: menuPanel contains 1 component which is a RectTransform. It sits in a Canvas which RenderMode is Screen Space - Overlay, so this does auto-position depending on screen width. What is Layout exactly? Thing is, if I use more simple ease types, it works fine.

Comment: are you using `ContentSizeFItter` anywhere ?

Comment: No, not that I knowingly have.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but just in case anyone else is having similar problems - you'll need to disable the Rigidbody attached to the game object you're tweening to avoid getting unpredictable behaviour in your raycast.